# How should I handle my "too localized" question

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

I have a question I posted an answer to:
[Access Selected Items from List View](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95025/access-selected-items-from-list-view/95216#95216)

I didn't mark it as answered - I feel based on what it took to get it solved it may be one of that is "too localized".  What's the proper way to handle this - Should I leave it or delete it?

Answer (score 2):

I read the answer and understood how this could be used in other similar scenarios. In addition, since I gained knowledge from your post, others are likely to benefit as well.

A lot of our questions and answers are very localized and specific. This doesn't mean others can't benefit from these posts. In SharePoint you sometimes need to be very specific, which means this is actually good. Maybe that's why the [too localized close reason is obsolete today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/180230)?

I think you should add the [bdc](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bdc) tag to the question and mark your answer as the accepted answer. If I run in to a similar problem, I know where to find one solution!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will do just that.